# How to get corresponding fields when selecting specific columns?

Tags: go, sqlx

Here is the code:

```golang
// User Model
type User struct {
    UserID        int           `db:"user_id"`
    UserNme       string        `db:"user_nme"`
    UserEmail     string        `db:"user_email"`
    UserAddressID sql.NullInt64 `db:"user_address_id"`
}
```

```golang
func (ur *userRepository) FindAll() ([]models.User, error) {
    var users []models.User
    query := "select user_nme from users"
    err := ur.Db.Select(&users, query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return users, nil
}
```

Result:

```sh
&[]models.User{models.User{UserID:0, UserNme:"Jay Durgan", UserEmail:"", UserAddressID:sql.NullInt64{Int64:0, Valid:false}}, models.User{UserID:0, UserNme:"Arne Balistreri", UserEmail:"", UserAddressID:sql.NullInt64{Int64:0, Valid:false}}, models.User{UserID:0, UserNme:"Greg Willms", UserEmail:"", UserAddressID:sql.NullInt64{Int64:0, Valid:false}}, models.User{UserID:0, UserNme:"Lady Aisha McLaughlin", UserEmail:"", UserAddressID:sql.NullInt64{Int64:0, Valid:false}}, models.User{UserID:0, UserNme:"Mrs. Phoebe Boyle", UserEmail:"", UserAddressID:sql.NullInt64{Int64:0, Valid:false}}}%
```

As you can see, I didn't query `user_id`, `user_email` and `user_address_id` columns, but the result give me these fields with zero value.

So, is there a way only get the fields correspond to the queried columns?
Beside, I don't want to write it like this: `&user.userNme`, `&user.xxx`, `&user.xxx` which means write each field and populate it. It's too verbose.

Expected result is: `{UserNme: "Jay Durgan"}`...

Comment: Erm... You explicitly ask only to return `user_nme` for all users, which will simply return a list of usernames, no additional values. How should Go populate those fields, then?

Comment: Furthermore, you do what is called „stuttering“ amongst gophers: `User.UserEmail`. Makes more sense to call it `User.Email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using struct, you can't.

The other fields will still be there with it's zero value. The fields are property of the struct so whether you need it or not, whether it stored retrieved value from db operation or not, all the fields will still be there.

The only solution for your case is by using map, so only value of correspondent fields will be retrieved.

```golang
var users []map[string]interface{}
query := "select user_nme from users"
err := ur.Db.Select(&users, query)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Result:

```
&[]map[string]interface{}{map[string]interface{}{UserNme:"Jay Durgan"}, ...}
```

Comment: This way will lose static type for `user`, because `interface{}` means `any` type.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
func (ur *userRepository) FindAll() ([]models.User, error) {
    users := []models.User{}.UserNme
    query := "select user_nme from users"
    err := ur.Db.Select(&users, query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return users, nil
}
```

Also you can follow this link

http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html

Comment: I want to get the queried fields, not all

Comment: you can use only  `users.UserName`